# How to edit/save IBM watson assistant conditional slot values for context variables?

Tags: watson-dialog, watson-assistant

I am trying to create a chatbot for booking flight tickets in watson assistant. The problem is that I want to enable the slot of **return_date** only when the trip is  a **roundtrip**. But on testing the bot the context variable of $return_date is not getting reflected where as the **$start_date** is getting updated with the value of **sys-date** entered when prompted for **return_date**.

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TCWMB.png)

[pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWw90.png)

Also when trying if the user enters *"I want to book roundtrip tickets for 4 people in economy class"* then the bot asks for the remaining slot values but does not invoke the slot asking for the return date even though the trip type is mentioned in the conversation.

[pic 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVaVL.png)

[pic 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8YSX.png)

[pic 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yeh6l.png)

Please suggest whether the flow needs to be changed or changes in the JSON editor will solve this problem.

Comment: Hm, you might want to share the whole workspace for this one (or at least workspace with frame in question). From my experience conditional slots works ok. Next is a wild guess but what might happen here though is that when filling up a slot expecting non-date entity and the user supplies a date entity then the system wrongly assumes that this new date entity is a correction of previously filled up entity (start_date) and replaces it. This functionality is there to allow for corrections.